# Updating constructor parameter before object construction

Tags: scala

Is there a way to update a constructor parameter before object initialization in scala. Sharing the following code to explain the purpose of this question. If not what would be the best practice?

```
case class example(p1:String,p2:String){
   if(p1=="a")
      p2="updated"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can override the default `apply` on the **companion object**.

```
object Example {
  def apply(p1: String, p2: String): Example =
    if (p1 == "a") new Example(p1, p2 = "updated")
    else new Example(p1, p2)
}

Example(p1 = "a", p2 = "b")
// res: Example(a, updated)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have got couple of choices here, Luis answer works but there are couple of holes you should be aware of. Have a look at below examples:

```scala
    case class Example private (p1:String,p2:String)

    object Example {
      def apply(p1: String, p2: String): Example =
        if (p1 == "a") new Example(p1, p2 = "updated")
        else new Example(p1, p2)
    }

    object Test extends App {
      val e = Example("a", "Ignore")
      println(e)

      // copy method generated by compiler does not invoke your original 
      // factory and hence bypasses your validations from apply method
      val e2 = Example("b", "valid").copy(p1 = "a") 
      println(e2)

    }
    //======== Output ===========
    //Example(a,updated)
    //Example(a,valid)


    sealed abstract case class Example2 private (p1:String, p2:String) {
      // By marking case class sealed, compiler does not generate copy  
      // method, you can write your own and apply your validations
      def copy(p1: String = p1, p2: String = p2) = Example2(p1, p2)
    }

    object Example2 {
      def apply(p1: String, p2: String): Example2 =
        if (p1 == "a") new Example2(p1, p2 = "updated"){}
        else new Example2(p1, p2){}
    }

    object Test2 extends App {
      val e = Example2("a", "Ignore")
      println(e)

      // does not compile
      val e2 = Example2("b", "valid").copy(p1 = "a")
      println(e2)

    }

    // ========= Output ===========
    //Example2(a,updated)
    //Example2(a,updated)
```